# Как обнаружить цепочку редиректов?

Tags: php

На сайте есть куча редиректов, которые размазаны по php роутингу. И возникают ситуации вроде

> /site/loop1 > /site/loop2
>
> /site/loop2 > /site/loop3
>
> /site/loop3 > /site/loop4
>
> /site/loop4 > /site/loop5
>
> /site/loop5 > /site/loop6

Я отдаю себе отчётность в том что перед редиректом возможно "что-то" происходит(в сессию пишется или еще что). Но от этого явно нужно избавляться, чтоб в конечном итоге получился прямой редирект

> /site/loop1 > /site/loop6

Благо хоть все редиректы сделанны через обёртку, некую функцию redirect, в которой я бы хотел складывать редиректы в стек и если формировалась цепочка. На конечной точке выхода, мне она куда-то писалась(например в базу данных). Для дальнейшего распутывания этого клубка.

Пока что в голову приходит только добавлять в сессию `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` при каждом редиректе и анализировать после выхода из цепочки.

Как вообще это правильно огранизовать, чтоб я велосипедов не наделал.

Comment: Откуда они у вас берутся, эти редиректы? Причина их создания?

Comment: А что, вы не умеете пользоваться дебагом?

Comment: @Visman, Добрые люди понаставили. В основном СЕОшники "оптимизируют". А потом удивляются что страницы долго открываются.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский. Видимо что нет. Поподробней. Есть автоматизированные готовые решения?

Comment: @Ninazu, если `СЕОшники "оптимизируют"`, то эти редиректы наверняка хранятся в базе!? Может у вас там даже отдельная таблица для редиректов заведена?

Comment: @Visman - нет, у нас всё не как у людей) Немного уточню. СЕОшники дёргают какого-то бекендщика из другого отдела и он быдлячит. Они даже не своими руками эту гнусть творят. В общем это в прошлом. Но нужно расхлебать то что натворили за всё время

Comment: @Ninazu дебажат обычно руками. Выставляют точки останова в программе и медленно проходят построчно куски кода переходя из одной точки в другую, заходя в одну функцию и выходя из нее (если это требуется), и отслеживая при этом стектрейс (откуда пришел)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский количество URL - тысячи. Ручная или полу ручная проверки неприемлемы.

Comment: @Ninazu переписывайте с нуля ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

Я бы попробовал следующий метод, возможно он окажется рабочим:

1. Внутри функции redirect создаем или добавляем в конец обособленной
   cookie URL редиректа. Например, при третьем редиректе будет уже
   такое значение в cookie: "/site/loop1;/site/loop2;/site/loop3"
2. При конечном скрипте приложения (перед отдачей ответа клиенту)
       проверяйте в ответе наличие заголовка "Location". Если его нет, то
       данное значение cookie записывайте в БД любым удобным способом и
       обнуляйте эту cookie
3. ...
4. Profit!

Comment: Я тоже подумал об куках вначале. Иначе как еще заставить клиента отдать то что мы ему отправляем. Но думаю что в сессию будет правильней. Возможна ситуация когда редирект идёт на поддомен или алиас к примеру а потом обратно. Ну и куки могут быть отключены)

Answer (score 0):

Напишите плагин, например для Chrome достаточно просто это сделать, и при открытии на одной из вкладок нужного сайта следите за эволюцией страницы.
Это если редирект отправляется клиенту, а не полностью отрабатывает внутри "задней части" (бэкенд) сайта.